# html table cellspacing not working within div

Tags: html, css

I have this code for a table which is very simple:

```
        <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
            <tr>
                <td><div id="mini_window"></div></td>
                <td><div id="mini_window"></div></td>
                <td><div id="mini_window"></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

This table code is within this div:

```
#body_content {
    top: 30%;
    left: 36%;
    width:70%;
    height:18em;
    margin-top: -9em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
    margin-left: -15em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    /*background-color: #f3f3f3;*/
    position:fixed;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

and within the table cells, there is the mini_window div that is:

```
#mini_window {
    top: 50%;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    margin-top: 20px; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;*/
    /*border-top: 1px solid #ccc;*/
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    /*direction: rtl;*/
}
```

It looks like the attached picture and that is not what I wanted. I need between each div say 20px more or less. What is going wrong?

[image]

UPDATE: Include the whole source of that page:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php   include_once('required_css.php'); ?>
<?php   include_once('required_js.php'); ?>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

</head>
<body>
    <?php include_once('header.php'); ?>

    <div id="body_content">
        <h1>ما الجديد؟</h1>
        <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
            <tr>
                <td><div id="mini_window"></div></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><div id="mini_window"></div></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><div id="mini_window"></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WkQme/

Comment: the link doesn't work...

Comment: Aye now it does. Yes that's exactly what I want but I am unable to get it to work. I hard refresh to ensure not cache and still same problem.

Comment: Well the fiddle is based on the code you posted here. Do you have other code that might be causing a conflict?

Comment: Nope pretty certain...just single project on the environment...nothing running in parallel

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. Changing `#mini_window` to a class may solve your problem.

Comment: Try adding `table {border-spacing:20px; }` to your css.

Comment: aaa DOCTYPE html you declared it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add margin: 10px;

```
#mini_window {
    top: 50%;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;*/
    /*border-top: 1px solid #ccc;*/
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    /*direction: rtl;*/
}
```